# Firefox 5 Cross-Domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, firefox

Since Firefox 5 was recently released I wanted to test if a web page I am working on would work on Firefox 5. However, my webpage which works fine in Firefox 4 is having problems in Firefox 5 with cross-domain requests. Does anyone know what changes in Firefox 5 could have changed this behavior? I am using the following code to allow  cross domain requests in Firefox 5 (Again this code works fine in Firefox 4)

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead UniversalBrowserWrite");
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC Mozilla was planning to remove the enablePrivilege function for a while. Looks like they started for real with Firefox 5. See for example https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=667312 for some discussion and some more links.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

it says: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header indicates whether a resource can be shared based by returning the value of the Origin request header in the response.

by doing this, you avoid security risks, and it should start working.